PySide6 detect if mouse pressed outside of widget
I have a GUI that needs a combo box that contains check boxes. From what I understand there are not any built in methods to create a QComboBox with checkboxes instead of buttons. Therefore, I'm attempting to make my own. I created a new class that inherent from QPushButton, however it creates a QFrame with checkboxes below it whenever you click the button. This works correctly, however I want the QFrame to disappear when you click somewhere else in the GUI. However, the mouse pressed event only emits a signal when you click inside the QFrame.
The code below is what I currently have. I'm relatively new to coding, so please let me know if there are any inherent problems. I'm assuming I can have a work around by creating some sort of signal that emits in the main program, however, I want to be able to use this class just as any other QWidget across my different PySide programs.
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QTabWidget, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel,QScrollArea,QHBoxLayout,QPushButton,QFrame,QCheckBox
from scheduling_widget import Schedule


class combo_check_box(QWidget,Qt):
    def __init__(self,button_name):
        super().__init__()
        self.items = {} #items inside combobox

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.button = QPushButton(button_name) #button that user clicks to trigger combobox
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.button)
        self.vbox.addStretch()
        self.button.pressed.connect(self.show_drop_down)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
    
    def add_item(self,item:str, value = True):
        self.items[item] = value



    def show_drop_down(self):
        #creates frame that contains check boxes
        self.frame = checkbox_frame(self)
        self.frame.setWidgetResizable(False)
        self.frame.show()
        self.frame.setGeometry(self.button.pos().x()-9, self.button.pos().y()+self.button.height(), self.width(), 125)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        #this does not work as intended
        self.frame.hide()




class checkbox_frame(QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.Qbox_button = parent
        widget = QWidget()
        #self.setStyleSheet("border:1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); ")
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.reset_layout()
        widget.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.setWidget(widget)
    
    def reset_layout(self):
        self.clearLayout(self.vbox)
        for items in self.Qbox_button.items: #dictionary with all items and their state
            button = QCheckBox(items)
            button.setChecked(self.Qbox_button.items[items])
            self.vbox.addWidget(button)
        



    def clearLayout(self, layout):
        if layout is not None:
            while layout.count():
                item = layout.takeAt(0)
                widget = item.widget()
                if widget is not None:
                    widget.deleteLater()
                else:
                    self.clearLayout(item.layout())

I haven't fully finished the combobox code, but the general idea is above^

You may consider using self.setWindowFlag(Qt.Popup), and, in any case, the popup should be a separate window, while right now it's part of it. Note that: 1. right now you keep creating new checkbox_frame objects, which means a memory waste; 2. the Qt inheritance is wrong (it just happen to work, but it's completely inappropriate), remove it; 3. classes should always have capitalized names, so that they can be easily distinguished from variables or functions, see the Style Guide for Python Code (but the convention is common for most languages).
